# Как валидировать изображения на NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, нейронные-сети, валидация

Пишу небольшой проект, вот задумался над такой вещью, а какой правильный нынче подход можно взять для проверки изображений (загруженных пользователями) на adult контент например или на наличие лица на фотографии. Использовать самодельную нейронку или может какое API есть удобное?